# How can I save GifDrawable to gallery?

Tags: android, save, gallery, gif, show

I have two questions.

1 - I tried to add a gif to the image using the GifDrawable library, but when I ran the code, only the gif appeared, the image was not show.

```
private Drawable ShowGif() {
    Drawable drawable = null;
    try {
        drawable = new GifDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.gifone);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.scale(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels, getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0,0, null);
        drawable.draw(canvas);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return drawable;
}
```

2 - I want to save the ShowGif to the gallery, how can I do that?